# Writing easy to testable, scalable and maintainable codes

Tags: elixir

I am using protocol in hope, to write a easy testable, scalable and maintainable codes

The protocol definition and implementation looks as follow:

```
defmodule SapOdataService.Auth do
  alias SapOdataService.Auth.UserLogin
  alias SapOdataService.Auth.UserInfo

  defprotocol Auth do
    @moduledoc """
     Protocol for SAP authentication.
    """
    def sign_in(data)
  end

  defimpl Auth, for: UserLogin do
    def sign_in(user) do
      %UserInfo{firstname: "Foo", lastname: "Boo", basic_auth: "Basic FooBoo"}
    end
  end
end
```

the user login struct(user_login.ex):

```
defmodule SapOdataService.Auth.UserLogin do

  defstruct username: nil, password: nil
  @type t :: %__MODULE__{username: String.t, password: String.t}

end
```

the user info struct(user_info.ex):

```
defmodule SapOdataService.Auth.UserInfo do

  defstruct firstname: nil, lastname: nil, basic_auth: nil
  @type t :: %__MODULE__{firstname: String.t, lastname: String.t, basic_auth: String.t}

end
```

As you can see the code above, the implementation of `userlogin`:

```
defimpl Auth, for: UserLogin do
    def sign_in(user) do
      %UserInfo{firstname: "Foo", lastname: "Boo", basic_auth: "Basic FooBoo"}
    end
  end
```

The `sign_in` function will make a http post request to server, if the given authorization was correct or not.

For the request, I use `HTTPoison` library for make a request to the server.

Supposed, in one day `HTTPoison` will not exists anymore and some developers develop new HTTP client and then I have to replace `HTTPoison` through new HTTP client.

My goal is, to write codes easy to scale and maintain.

I read the wonderful [article](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2015/10/mocks-and-explicit-contracts/) about mock from José, he suggests to use protocol and pass the dependency as the parameter to function. That is the point, why I use he protocol over behaviour.

In addition, how to force the protocol definition to return particular type. In my case, I would like to do like this:

```
defprotocol Auth do
  @moduledoc """
   Protocol for SAP authentication.
  """
  @spec sign_in(data) :: UserInfo.t
  def sign_in(data)
end
```

Comment: Just because you are using the word `force` here. I just wanted to make sure that you know the compiler does not enforce any of the specifications you set in your program. You will need to use something like [`dialyzer`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/dialyzer.html) to check if your code follows the specifications you set.

Comment: This is just as broad as the last version of the question you posted.  How to write maintainable, scalable, easily testable code could be (and has been) the subject of whole books.  Narrow your question.  Vote to close.

Comment: In addition to what @OnorioCatenacci said, I would add that removing the question and posting the almost same one in a couple of hours, without even trying to state the question and provide the MCVE, sounds like nearly a violation of the rules of this site. You have stated that you had read an article and decided to use a protocol. Good for you, but still, **what is your question?**